# Highlight rows programatically in AgGrid with React

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I am trying to use AgGrid together with a graph to display some data. AgGrid displays the data as a table, and then right next to it I am plotting the data on a chart for a visual representation.

What I want to do is highlight rows in the table when I mouseover them on the graph. Using something like `useState` is really quite heavy and causes a full re-render which makes the table very jittery, so I would like to use something like [Zustand with transient updates](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand#transient-updates-for-often-occuring-state-changes) and then subscribe to the mouseover state.

What I cannot figure out, is how I could just use the API to apply a class to the grid though. There are [several ways](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-styles/) to apply styles it seems, however no matter how I do it the outcome is not a smooth highlighting of the rows that should be highlighted.

Has anyone tried to do something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While asking this question I tried to create a working example to show what I had some so far, and in doing so I actually solved the issue.

The sandbox is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/aggrid-highlight-based-on-external-data-h9itj6?file=/src/components/Table.tsx:192-307).

The important part is the subscription to the state change from the zustand data store. From here we can call a function that uses the AgGrid API to set the row status to 'selected', which will highlight it for us.

```js
...
 const setRowHighlight = (e: any) => {
    if (gridRef && gridRef.current) {
      const rowNode: RowNode = gridRef.current.api.getRowNode(e);
      rowNode.setSelected(true);
    }
  };
  React.useEffect(
    () =>
      useZustandStore.subscribe(
        setRowHighlight,
        (state: any) => state.highlighted
      ),
    []
  );
...
```

I have not copied all the code as there's a bit too much, however this should highlight what is happening.